# Error in VB Function in SSIS but not in VisualStudio

Tags: vb.net, ssis

I have some VB.Net code that I'm trying to add to a SSIS package.  The code runs fine in VisualStudio 2012 and when I compile it there are no errors and the executable runs as well.  When I insert the code into an SSIS package Script Task and copy/paste my code in I'm getting an error in one of my functions:

'Any' is not a member of 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(Of String)'.

I copied and pasted the main body of the code exactly and inserted one Imports line:

```
#Region "Imports"
Imports System
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Math
Imports System.IO 'Added this one Imports
Imports Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime
#End Region

<Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.SSISScriptTaskEntryPointAttribute()> _
<System.CLSCompliantAttribute(False)> _
Partial Public Class ScriptMain
Inherits Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTARTScriptObjectModelBase


Public Sub Main()
    Dim sDirectoryRoot As String = "\\Server\Drive$\SubFolder\SubFolder2\"
    Dim dirList As New DirectoryInfo(sDirectoryRoot)
    ListFiles(dirList)
    Dts.TaskResult = ScriptResults.Success 'left this line from SSIS default
End Sub

Public Sub ListFiles(ByVal dirList As DirectoryInfo)
Dim bEmpty As Boolean = False
[...] bunch of code with no errors.  Actual function call below where clientdir is a directory path
bEmpty = IsDirectoryEmpty(clientdir.ToString)

End Sub

Public Function IsDirectoryEmpty(ByVal path As String) As Boolean
    Return Not (Directory.EnumerateFileSystemEntries(path).Any())
End Function
```

The Directory.EnumerateFileSystemEntries(path).Any is underlined with the 'Any' is not a member of 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(Of String)' error.  I can't figure out why it runs fine in Visual Studio, but when I use the Edit Script button in the Script Task Editor (which starts another instance of Visual Studio) it errors out.

Comment: Compare the .net target versions between your .net app and your SSIS version. Is one targeting the 3.5 framework and the other using 4.0 or 4.5?

Comment: SSIS was targeting 4.0 and my main app was targeting 4.5, but it was the missing Imports System.Linq that @jmcilhinney pointed out that was the problem.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Any` is an extension method and, as with all extension methods, requires that you import the appropriate namespace.  It is, in fact, the `System.Linq.Enumerable.Any` method, hence you must import the `System.Linq` namespace.  That's probably done at the project level by default in your non-SSIS project.  Note that you will also have to have referenced the System.Core.dll assembly.

Comment: System.Linq was checked in the references of the original project, and adding it to the Imports section of the SSIS package eliminated the error.  I got stuck on the Directory.EnumerateFileSystemEntries part of the error.  (Sadly I had the Enumerable.Any MSDN page open but I didn't look at the namespace: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb337697 )  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @jmcihinney and 5 months later ran into the same thing and found my question and your answer.  Thanks again, Imports System.Linq fixed it again.